# Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, parsing, dart, double, warnings

```
FeelsLike.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    day = double.parse(json['day']);
    night = double.parse(json['night']);
    eve = double.parse(json['eve']);
    morn = double.parse(json['morn']);
  }
```

The above code gives the warning **Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

I have also tried..

```
 FeelsLike.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    day = (json['day']).toDouble;
    night = (json['night']).toDouble();
    eve = (json['eve']).toDouble();
    morn = (json['morn']).toDouble();
  }
```

but then it gives the warning like **Unhandled Exception: type '() => double' is not a subtype of type 'double'**

I have also tried ..

```
FeelsLike.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    day = double.parse((json['day'])).toDouble();
    night = double.parse((json['night'])).toDouble();
    eve = double.parse((json['eve'])).toDouble();
    morn = double.parse((json['morn'])).toDouble();
  }
```

Then it gives me a warning something like this **Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'**

can someone please tell me how to get rid of that warning?

Comment: Can you add the json you get?

Comment: @FelipeVergara sure its quite long

Comment: Its quite lengthy can post.

Comment: I understand, could you create your model with this application? You can paste your object and it automatically generates your model with functions. (https://app.quicktype.io/)

Comment: You don't need to post the whole JSON. Just add any small portion of the JSON that shows the values for the "day", "night", "eve", and "morn" values you are attempting to parse.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing a double to the double.parse() function this function expects string not a double
when you parse the JSON string to Map<String, dynamic> with JsonDecode function or other similar functions this functions will recognize the basic primitive types used in the JSON and will translate them to the same equivalent type in dart so when you call a json['night'] its type is double not string and it doesn't need to be parsed again to double
for example, if you have a JSON like this

```
{
 "Point":9.5
}
```

when you parse this function will return a Map<String, dynamic> object which contains a key with the name of "Point" that has a value of 9.5 with double type, not a string type
also, this is true for the list, int, double, string types, and nested JSON objects that have Map<string, dynamic> types
note that there is a difference between

```
{
  "Point":9.5
}
```

and

```
{
  "Point":"9.5"
}
```

point value in the first one is double and in the second one because of quotes is a string

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can try to parse only from a string not from a double or integer.

```
external static double parse(String source,
      [@deprecated double onError(String source)?]);
```

As you can see above. You should pass a string in the parameter. So, try one of these:

```
double.parse(json['day'].toString());
```

or

```
double.tryParse(json['day'].toString());
```

Notice that tryParse() returns null if fails, but parse() will throw exception if fails.